# std library map and template functions

Tags: c++, dictionary

I really don't understand why this code

```
#include <map>

template<typename T, typename U> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,
        const std::map<T,U>& input)
{
    for (std::map<typename T,typename U>::iterator it=input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it)
    {
        o << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
    }
    return o;
}
```

returns this compilation error:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
error: provided for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
```

can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 4):

You should write typename before the iterator declaration and use const_iterator:

`for (typename std::map<T,U>::const_iterator it=input.begin(); it!=input.end(); ++it`

The argument of the operator << requires const objects. So elements of the map must be const. To achieve this one uses a const_iterator. 
The typename in the declaration of the iterator is required to indicate that the following expression is a nested template class depending on the types T and U.

See also this question:
[Making sense of arguments to a function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632475/making-sense-of-arguments-to-a-function-template)

Comment: Or even better, use `auto`: `for (auto it = input.begin(); ...` or even the range-based for loop: `for (auto& pair : input)`